# Как правильно писать "подчинить цеха" или "подчинить цехи?

Tags: род-существительного

Как правильно писать "подчинить цеха" или "подчинить цехи"

Answer (score 5):

До 80-х годов так было:|Малый академический словарь. 1. (мн. це́хи).
В средние века в Западной Европе: городская организация ремесленников одной профессии.
2. (мн. це́хи и разг. цеха́).
Основное производственное подразделение промышленного предприятия.
Инструментальные цехи.
Большой толковый словарь - то же самое:
1. мн.: цехи и (разг.) цеха.
Основное производственное подразделение промышленного предприятия. Инструментальный ц. Мартеновский ц.
НО: только ЦЕХИ башмачников, кузнецов.

Сейчас другая картина: разговорное цеха' стало нормой и предпочтительно:
Словарь "Русское словесное ударение"-
1.цех, цеха, в цеху и в цехе, о цехе; мн. цеха, -ов (отдел промышленного предприятия) ;
2.цех, цеха, в цехе; мн.цехи, цехов (средневековая организация ремесленников)

Так что подчинить цеха - более нормативно, цехи - устаревшее значение объединения ремесленников или замкнутой группировки.

Answer (score 1):

Множественное число от цех цеха и цехи равнодопустимо. Соответственно и варианты винительного падежа одинаково возможны.

А что имеется в виду? "Цех" вроде как элемент структуры произхводственнного предприятия, подразделение, в каком смысле его можно подчинить?
Есть ещё устаревшее значение слова "цех", средневековая организация производственников, там бы я предпочел вариант "цехи", но это субъективно.